# Retrieve posts with their latest comment in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model, cakephp-2.x

Say I have a model `Post` and a model `Comment` related as follows:

```
Post hasMany Comment 
Comment belongsTo Post
```

How do use `find('all')` to retrieve every `Post` with its associated latest `Comment`?

I have tried defining a `hasOne` relationship in `Post` as:

```
var $hasOne = array('LatestComment' => array('className' => 'Comment', 'order' => 'LatestComment.created DESC'));
```

But when I do a `Post->find('all')` it returns every `Post` multiple times, once per each `Comment`, with `LatestComment` set to the different `Comments`.

Comment: might be related to my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707048/last-x-blog-entries-but-only-once-per-user/11933591#11933591

Answer (score 2):

You can add 'limit' => 1 to your array of parameters to only return one comment.

Alternatively, instead of defining another relationship, you can simply limit the number of comments returned when you perform the find, using the Containable behaviour.

```
$this->Post->find('all',array(
                     'contain' => array(
                          'Comment' => array(
                              'order' => 'Comment.created DESC',
                              'limit' => 1
                          )
                      )
                  );
```

This is useful if you want to filter any related sets without defining relationships - by author, or within a date range, for example.

Make sure that you add the Containable behaviour to any model that you reference.

Comment: I second that. Always use Containable!

Comment: hasOne relationships does not seem to support the option 'limit' (see http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together) Your second suggestion works, but I would have liked to see a way to do this with a hasOne relationship so latestComment can be used as any other related model (automatically added to queries).

Comment: You could use hasMany and limit that to 1 result. It seems counter-intuitive, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the duplicates you want to use: GROUP BY in your find all query. I believe Cake has a 'group' => option as well.

Comment: This does give me only one of each Post, but not with the right (the latest) Comment.

Comment: Right you need to extend it to do your other part of the query. Sort by DESC and then get the first element from the array result.