# CakePHP: select users who have 1 or more posts

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have two tables: `users` and `posts`. I'm trying to select any users that have at least one post.

I'm guessing this require either a join or a subselect. Is there something in CakePHP that makes this simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use counter caching, see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#belongsto

> counterCache: If set to true the associated Model will automatically
>   increase or decrease the “[singular_model_name]_count” field in the
>   foreign table whenever you do a save() or delete(). If it’s a string
>   then it’s the field name to use. The value in the counter field
>   represents the number of related rows. You can also specify multiple
>   counter caches by using an array where the key is field name and value
>   is the conditions. E.g.:
>
> array(
>       'recipes_count' => true,
>       'recipes_published' => array('Recipe.published' => 1) ) counterScope: Optional conditions array to use for updating counter
>   cache field.

No additional query needed in this case. It will automatically in- and decrease the count in the users table if you add/delete posts.

Example:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'counterCache' => true,
        'counterScope' => array(
            'published' => 1)));
```

Comment: This is great. If I add it after records have already been created, will it retroactively fill in the counts?

Comment: It will do it the next time you add or delete a record. Just take a look at the code, it's pretty simple. If you want to update them all at once write a shell script that will update all existing records or use a migration (github.com/cakedc/migrations)

Answer (score 1):

This should select all users that made 1 post or more

```
SELECT * FROM `users` as u
INNER JOIN `posts` as p ON p.user_id = u.id
```

In cake you should be able to do something like this:

```
$this->User->find('all', array('joins' =>
    array(
        'table' => 'posts',
        'alias' => 'p',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => array(
            'User.id = p.user_id'
        )
    )
);
```

[EDIT]

Maybe you could add

```
'group' => 'User.id'
```

or

```
'fields' => 'DISTINCT User.id, ...'
```

To remove duplicates entries

Comment: This query seems to return a bunch of dupes, one for each post I believe.

Comment: you could try to use a group statement to filter out the dupes. you could also try the answer to a problem very similar I recently had: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707048/last-x-blog-entries-but-only-once-per-user/11933591#11933591